# multiple WSDL definitions

Tags: wcf, web-services, wsdl

I'm hosting a WCF service on my localhost server and a separate app server. When looking at the WSDL from each server their definitions are entirely different.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

your wsdl can "appear" different depending on your bindings, but if your data types in your service are the same deployed on both servers, your schema for those types on each server should be consistent (though they might have a different namespace or be at a different url).

wsdl's are used for serialization / deserialization, if you've done it the same way on both servers they should show up the same way, but that may not always be the case (what you think is the same, especially with wcf is not always the case unless you've hand coded everything since wcf tends to be largely configuration driven).

Comment: It's the same executable being run on both servers. What baffles me is that I can use the methods on my local host but not from the app server. I thought that with the wsdl definitions being different it could have posed a problem.